# Responsive dropdown menu issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Having a few issues implementing a dropdown menu for the responsive side of my website.

- The cells are automatically padded apart from the top, and addding padding to the top to centre the text seems to increase padding on ALL sides.
- The cells have an even padding using an IE browser, but on firefox the height gos haywire.
- The method Im implementing uses :hover for the dropdown menu, will this cause problem on a mobile device?

Ive spent many days going through different methods for dropdown menus, is there a simpler or more standard way of implementing these?

(I'd prefer not to use javascript as I havent learnt the basics yet and like to understand what Im programming)

Really appreciate any help with this. Thankyou.

```
---HTML----

<div class="dropdown">
       <ul class="nav">
         <li><img class="btn" src="images/menuIcon.png"
                                   alt="Menu button" />
           <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="holisticMassage.htm">Holistic Massage</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutDuncan.htm">About Duncan</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonials.htm">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="prices.htm">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="map.htm">Location</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
   </div>

---/HTML---

----CSS----

.dropdown{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 }

.dropdown .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display:none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none; /** Remove list bullets */
  width:120%;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:1;
  }

.dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown ul li ul li{
   float: none;
   padding-top:10%;
   background-color: #E5E5E5;
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid grey;
 }

.btn {
     display: block;
}

 .menu li a{
   padding:0px;
 }

 .menu li a{
   font-family: gabriola, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size: 6vw;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #505050;
  }

  ul li:hover .menu {
     display: inline-block;
 }


---/CSS----
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using font-size: 6VW; which means viewport width, its responsive to the screen width, I'd use %, em or px.

Use :focus for touch devices.

Comment: It seems all of these are still renedering my text huge in Firefox but normal in IE. Also I dont think the cell padding problem is related to text size as even when the text is the desired size in firefox, the cell size is height is huge.